# How to autofit background image in ng-style

Tags: angularjs

A newbie question, just cannot find answer so far.

My page is 2 column grid system, following is the right column

```
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-lg-9" ng-style="{'background-
image':'url(123.jpg)', 'background-repeat': 'no-repeat', 'height':'
800px' }">
      <h1> {{message}} </h1>
            <div ng-view></div>
   </div>
```

Now height is fixed, I tried to let the image autofit with the browser size (for the right column part in the page), but it doesn't work.

Any hints please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "background-size" property in the style list to mention the width and height of the "background-image". Your code should be as below:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-lg-9" ng-style="{'background-
    image':'url(123.jpg)', 'background-repeat': 'no-repeat', 'height':'
    800px' 'background-size': '100% 800px' }">
       <h1> {{message}} </h1>
       <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to deal with this in CSS, the recommended styles of **background-size:** is **cover** since it scales the image into the container using a CSS implementation.

However, you should try other ones to see if they work better for you

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Also it may be better practice since you're using bootstrap to use the class `img-responsive`, bootstrap has a built in class of it's own and it scales the image appropiately based on the `col` it is in.

Answer (score 0):

Add **background-size: cover;** to your style

Change it to

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-lg-9" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(123.jpg)', 'background-repeat': 'no-repeat', 'background-size': 'cover'; }">
  <h1> {{message}} </h1>
        <div ng-view></div>   </div>
```

Hope it helps